# On site notification system

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, mootools

I was tasked to build a calendar and agenda library (I'm working on the CodeIgniter framework), that shows a calendar and the user has the possibility to set events on that calendar.
These events will have a notification system both email, and when the user is browsing the site, a popup.

My issue is how to approach the notification part when the user is on the site. The email is something that I already decided would be done trough a cronjob that will run every x minutes and check if there is any need to send a notification email.

The on site notification is something else.
How would I approach this? I just can't make a ajax request to the server every x seconds, since that would put an unnaceptable load on the system. (Of course when the user is eventually notified, a request must be made, to set the user as "remined" on the database).
I can't just depend on the user's date time, since he could be anywhere in the world and the time would be different.
How can I check that the user must be notified of a event, avoiding making repeated requests to the server? Would appreciate any input.

Comment: If you can't use the user's local time, how are you going to create the events in the first place?

Comment: Events of the calendar are always created taking the server date/time, not the user's.

Comment: ...which means, you don't need to know the user's local time to trigger the reminder, since you're dealing with your local time anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see using `setTimeout` to do this.  Say a user visits your page `$minutesTilDue` minutes prior the reminder being due.  Assuming jQuery/PHP:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       showEventReminder(<?php json_encode($event) ?>);
    }, <?php echo $minutesTilDue ?> * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Nothing too fancy, but depending on your requirements...

Cheers

Comment: might do. Going to take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Easily scalable notification systems use websockets, which today reach the majority of the users, even on mobile devices. Unfortunately, you'll need a websocket-enabled server - node, glassfish, whatever - this can't be done with standard PHP deployments (mod_php or fcgi). Server events (so called *server push*) are sent when they are generated, so once you have your websocket client-server pair, sending a reminder is just like sending an email.

Actually things are more complicated because most likely users won't be online at the exact time the reminder should pop up. I suggest a notification icon which is refreshed each time the user hits a page. This way your calendar system (suppose a cronjob) will simply update a flag for the user row in the DB, and when you build the page, you already know if there reminders (let's say, in the next 60 minutes) or not, and choose the icon accordingly. At this point, you have two choices:

1. sending the reminders to the client along with each and every request (it could be a waste of bandwidth, but I don't thing a JSON-encoded list of events is so heavyweight)
2. Download the reminders asynchronously on demand, ie only when the user hits the notification icon

This scenario lets you reuse the PHP environment and code, and doesn't require another host for the websocket server. I think this is the best solution, even if this doesn't fulfill your requirement of a truly *popup reminder* triggered by the server at the right time. BTW, if you send events with every request, your javascript can pop up when needed - you can use `setTimeout()` for this.

Comment: Thanks. Will take this into consideration. But it might be overkill for my needs.